# Is possible to use a custom variable in Travis CI?

Tags: php, testing, composer-php, travis-ci, packagist

I know that there are some default variables for testing with different environments, like the one (for PHP projects) like `SYMFONY_VERSION`.

My question is simple: would be possible to define a *custom* variable, for testing with a few specific version of another package (on which I'm depending on)?

I've tried:

```
env:
  - SYMFONY_VERSION=2.0.*
  - SYMFONY_VERSION=2.1.*
  - BUZZ_VERSION=0.6
  - BUZZ_VERSION=0.*

before_script:
  - composer require symfony/dependency-injection:${SYMFONY_VERSION} 
        kriswallsmith/buzz:${BUZZ_VERSION}
```

But it doesn't work, I've got a failed build due to "undefined index":

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/build-configuration/#Set-environment-variables

1. You need both symfony and buzz in one build, so they need to be placed in one line
2. Wildcard (`*`) should be quoted

Summing up:

```
env:
  - SYMFONY_VERSION="2.0.*" BUZZ_VERSION="0.6"
  - SYMFONY_VERSION="2.1.*" BUZZ_VERSION="0.*"
```

Comment: I'll try, thanks. The wildcard thing sounds strange to me. It works without quotes https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRest/blob/master/.travis.yml

Comment: As far as I know, the wildcard is fine unquoted as long as there is no path that matches the beginning of whatever the wildcard follows, but in general it's best to quote them for safety I think in shell scripts.